# Flex Web-Tier Setup

Tags: windows, apache-flex, apache, installation

This one has been driving me nuts for a few days now and I've tried Google but no luck (judging from my good luck with finding answers on google, this is a rarity for me not to find an answer).

To cut a long story short, I did have the capability to compile my mxml files via the browser on my local machine. I've had to do a reinstall but now I'm having problems trying to compile.

My current setup is:

WAMP 2.0i
- Apache 2.2.8
- PHP 5.2.8
- MySQL 5.1.36

FlashDevelop 3.0.0 RC1
Win XP

I've tried compiling in Firefox 3.5, IE8 & Chrome but all receive the same error:

---

Compilation results

Errors, warnings or exceptions were found while compiling null.Visit the online Flex documentation or API reference for further information.

An error occured on the server. Server error is: 'Error occurred in server thread; nested exception is: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: flex.license.License.(Ljava/util/Map;Ljava/lang/String;Lflex/license/Logger;)V'

---

I've followed the instructions from adobe:

http://labs.adobe.com/wiki/index.php/Flex_Module_for_Apache_and_IIS

but no luck. I can compile without an issue via CMD but I prefer to use the browser as I find that much faster. Has anyone run into this issue and solved it?

Cheers!
DNT

Edit:
I forgot to mentioned I've tried using the Flex 2 & 3 SDK to no avail.

Comment: Here's an update.

I just tried the flex SDK 4 just to see what happens and it compiles except I get a few errors... obviously a version issue.

I may be onto something... whatever that may be...

Comment: Did the same process with the flex 3 SDK (just realised I was dyslexic when I typed the flex 4 sdk above) and it's compiling but with errors.<br><br>
The only different thing I've done is after uninstalling the flex module is doing a reboot. Maybe that's made the difference? I usually just run CCleaner to clean out the registry entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I **FINALLY** found the answer!

Got a new pc for work so I had to reinstall everything and I've found the solution that worked flawlessly.

Use this link to download the Adobe Flex SDK which is over 100MB; ignore the Open Source Flex SDK download links. At the time of writing, I downloaded version 3.4.0.9271:

http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Download+Flex+3

Make sure you follow the **Installation Instructions** up until the **To install the Flex module** heading.

http://labs.adobe.com/wiki/index.php/Flex_Module_for_Apache_and_IIS#Installation

Then go to this page and under the main heading **Flex 3 Compiler Modules** then under the sub heading **3.0.0.477**, download the file **FlexModule_apache.exe** and follow the installation instructions and you should be home free!

http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Downloads

Answer (score 0):

I believe I can safely say I've answered my own question.

Rather than using a program to clear out the registry (eg ccleaner), run the uninstall on the "flex module for Apache & IIS" then do a reboot.

Once you get back into windows, 'stop all services' in wamp and check that your httpd.conf file has removed the entry:

```
#BEGIN FLEX  INSTALLER EDITS - REMOVE ONLY ON UNINSTALL
LoadModule flex_module "D:/your/path/to/modules/mod_flex.dll"
AddHandler flex .mxml
#END FLEX INSTALLER EDITS - REMOVE ONLY ON UNINSTALL
```

Now go wild and run the 'flex module for apache & IIS' installer, answer the questions and when you get to the end, do the reboot and it should work.

What a PITA!