# Browser Compilation Error for Flex

Tags: windows, apache-flex, browser, compilation

I'm having an odd problem that isn't mission critical since I can use the command line with no probs.

In my earlier post [[Flex Web-Tier Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141133/flex-web-tier-setup)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141133/flex-web-tier-setup), I had problems getting the web compiler to work.

Now that it's working I use this in a browser to compile:

```
http://localhost/flex/topsight.mxml?username=xxxxx&password=xxxxx
```

and I get this error as a result:

```
ERROR : Could not resolve to a component implementation.

349 <mx:filters>
350 <mx:DropShadowFilter alpha=".25" angle="90" />
351 </mx:filters>
```

Everything is legit and the most recommended solution is that the namespaces aren't correct. I've checked those and they're fine. Other answers I've come across relate to external components causing a problem but as you can see, I'm not using an external component.

Here's the kicker. If I do a compile via command line:

```
mxmlc topsight.mxml
```

it compiles perfectly.

Specs are still the same from the prior post and I'm using the Flex 3 SDK.

Not sure if this would help but I did the download from http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Download+Flex+3 and I clicked on the **Open Source Flex SDK - Milestone 3.3**

Cheers!
Adrian

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flex Web-Tier Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141133/flex-web-tier-setup)

Answer (score 0):

Only thing I can think of is that your compiler.conf can't find the Flex framework.  Does it work with just a:

`<mx:Application> </mx:Application>`

? ( basically no components )  There is an option in there flex_config that points to the SDK version you want the compiler to use.  I haven't used the web-tier in a *long* time so, I could be totally off track.

Comment: Hey dan,

Thanks for the suggestion but it compiled without a problem. I had a look at the config file but the only version I could set was the version of flash player to use (which is set to version 10.0.0).

I think I will try the stable builds (118MB & 25MB builds) and see if that makes a difference since I used the Milestone version.

Comment: Looks like I'll be sticking to cmd line compilation. Nothing works which is odd. I'll keep trying and will post a result (if any) when a solution is found.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you are trying to apply the filters to a custom component. If you change the filter's namespace from mx to that of the component you're applying it to it should work. ie. if you are trying:

```
 <bt:Rectangle x="187" y="80">
    <mx:filters>
        <mx:DropShadowFilter distance="4" angle="45" alpha="0.5"/>
    </mx:filters>
</bt:Rectangle>
```

It would become:

```
<bt:Rectangle x="187" y="80">
    <bt:filters>
        <mx:DropShadowFilter distance="4" angle="45" alpha="0.5"/>
    </bt:filters>
</bt:Rectangle>
```